# Where can I define the workgroup name

Tags: networking, xubuntu

Xubuntu 16.04: My network is configured and runs fine. But the pc is shown as part of the network "WORKGROUP". It should be part of "HOMENET".

Where can I configure that on the desktop?

Comment: Please post results of `grep 'workgroup' /etc/samba/smb.conf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks https://askubuntu.com/users/658578/toomanypets,
your comment solved it.

I had installed samba on that client. Other had no samba installed and did not have that problem.

I fixed it with:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Search the line (it should about the very first settings in the file) and change from

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

to

```
 workgroup = HOMENET
```

where I think the case does not matter. Save with Ctrl-o and exit with Ctrl-x. Finally, restart the samba service with

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

Hope it helps